# Github to bitbucket migration

Tags: github, migration, bitbucket

We are planning to migrate 15-20 repositories from GitHub to Bitbucket,
Is there any checklist of the all the items that we migrate?
It seems that PR, Issues can not be migrated with Bitbucket Import feature, is there any automated way to migrate the same?
Is there anything else that cannot be migrated with Bitbucket Import feature?
Any known issues/problems that can be faced?

Checked multiple blogs but could not find our answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitbucket import feature](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/import-a-repository/) seems to be strictly limited to code import (from CodePlex, GitHub, Google Code, SourceForge, Subversion, or another Git-based hosting site)

It won't manage issues, pull requests or merge requests.

And it won't manage user account migration, which means a collaborator would need to recreate their account on BitBucket, and [email aliases need to be configured](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-email-aliases/), in order to associate commits to the new (BitBucket) account.